# Issue trying to flag a duplicate

Tags: support

[This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/145247/vlc-main-decoder-error-failed-to-create-audio-output) appears to be a duplicate of [this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/142619/vlc-video-player-not-working-correctly-on-raspberry-pi-bullseye). However, the dialog under `close, duplicate` refuses to accept that; actually, it says, "Your search returned no matches; please try a different search". Why??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I went to try this yesterday and I thought the same thing happened as in your post, but today instead (I could be misremembering) I get:

[image]

However, if I use the normal search box in the top with the same term it finds the page and I then I'm able to copy the whole address from the browser location and paste that into the "Close" dialog search box and it finds the question and will allow me to use it as the dupe.

Not sure if I see those as duplicates though, so I did not.  But you should be free to.

I realize this is a bit awkward and you might want to post it as a bug in Meta, since it definitely looks like one either way (what happened with you, and my experience of the search not working period).

Comment: Nah - I've got enough of my own bugs; I'll let Meta worry this one. It also occurred to me that **since** the other question had no answers, that might be a reason **not** to classify it as a dupe. TBH, I was only looking for a way to get rid of some of the silly questions this site seems to be plagued with.